# Grails 2.0.1 Hibernate exception in foreign worker thread

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, grails

I have a Grails 2.0.1 app and I spawn worker threads. My worker threads use GORM to read/write domain objects from MySql. Given that the code that is accessing the DB is not inside of an HTTP request, I create a Hibernate session for the save() like this:

```
MyClass.withTransaction { status ->
    myClass.save()
}
```

I do that to resolve the "No Hibernate Session bound to thread" problem.

This worked fine on Grails 1.3.7.  I am currently attempting to upgrade to Grails 2.0.1, and am seeing an exception I do not understand.

The following stack trace shows the exception.

Although I recognize the exception, and normally resolve it via the "withTransaction" technique shown above, the thing that baffles me about this one is that it is happening on a ***worker thread that I did not create***.

```
Exception in thread "pool-12-thread-2" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryProxy.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryProxy.java:145)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.HibernateDomainClassValidator.validate(HibernateDomainClassValidator.java:51)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:121)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.ValidatePersistentMethod.doInvokeInternal(ValidatePersistentMethod.java:119)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.metaclass.AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.invoke(AbstractDynamicPersistentMethod.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:189)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormValidationApi.validate(HibernateGormEnhancer.groovy:702)
at com......MyClass.validate(MyClass.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$7.call(ClosureEventListener.java:282)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener$7.call(ClosureEventListener.java:267)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.doWithManualSession(ClosureEventListener.java:302)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventListener.onPreUpdate(ClosureEventListener.java:267)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPreUpdate(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:164)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.EventTriggeringInterceptor.onPersistenceEvent(EventTriggeringInterceptor.java:89)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPersistenceEventListener.java:46)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:92)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I am hoping someone can enlighten me regarding:

1. where this worker thread pool originates from?
2. why is is doing a preUpdate event (when I believe the save in my thread already did a successful validate and save
3. Can I somehow config my app such that these foreign worker threads are not there
4. If #3 can't be pulled off, how can I do the equivalent of a "withTransaction" over in the worker thread code that I do not "own"

Comment: The Grails 2.0.1 doc says "Grails now executes validation routines when the underlying Hibernate session is flushed to ensure that no invalid objects are persisted". I am now thinking that the thread I showed in the stack trace above may be the hibernate write-behind thread that is flushing the session, and doing the (redundant ?) validation already performed in my thread. I still do not understand how to deal with the lack of a hibernate session on this thread (especially if it is indeed the write-behind session flusher thread).

Comment: this might be a good task for a profiling tool or JConsole so you can observe what is going one with the threads in your application

Comment: Maybe there's a clue at the end of the exception message? "and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here". Perhaps your write-behind flushing theory is correct, but for whatever reason it's trying to create a Hibernate session but can't?